# Could moderators of a Stack Exchange site be granted access to Google Analytics, for SEO purposes?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stackexchange-2.0, search-engine, analytics

Would it be possible for moderators of a Stack Exchange 2.0 site to get access to Google Analytics for the site?

When I was running [Basically Money](http://www.basicallymoney.com), the SE 1.0 version of [money.stackexchange.com](http://money.stackexchange.com), I found it useful to examine the Google Analytics reports for my site – in particular, the kinds of **keywords** that were successful in bringing users to the site via the search engines.

I would use the knowledge discovered about keywords to help **make the question titles better.**

More often than not, better titles resulted in increased natural search traffic, and such traffic can be good, free exposure for a site.

Understanding what people are searching for, where users are coming from, etc. would be helpful in trying to promote a new Stack Exchange site.

Could moderators of Stack Exchange 2.0 sites be granted read access to such analytics?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Moderators have access to a panel which shows them analytics now.

Comment: Is this something that can reasonably be extended to users above a reputation level (20-50k, perhaps) ?

Answer (score 12):

Either that or have the Stackexchange team create a small application using the Analytics API so that moderators can have access to that.

Comment: A **much** better idea.

Comment: Sure, if it provides the same kind of useful information.  Google Analytics itself is awesome, though.

Comment: @Chris But then they have to manage account access and information for when moderators change hands. In my example, they simply need to make the information available on a moderator panel on the target site. As moderators come and go, they gain/lose access accordingly (and more importantly, automatically).

Comment: Sure, but building similar capabilities - even if simpler - may be much more work than managing a handful of Google accounts that are authorized for read access for any given site.  Besides, many mods might not even care to request it.  In any case, leave aside *how* the data is exposed .. it's the exposing of it, somehow, that matters.

Comment: @Chris what works for 1 SE site or 10 does not work for 100, or a thousand.